# git equivalent for rename

Tags: git, bash, rename, git-mv

In bash I can do `find . -name jndi.properties -exec rename 's/jndi/environment/' {} \;` to recursively find all jndi.propertie files and have them renamed to environment.properties.

But git status does not recognize the mv, it shows the deletion and addition separately. How can I do recursive `git mv`?

Comment: find . -name jndi.properties -exec git mv <oldFileName> 's/jndi/environment/' {} \;

Comment: man git-status. There is an option to detect renames. And technically IT IS deletion and addition in git internals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're doing an exact match on the name, you don't really need to do a dynamic substitution, do you?  If your `find` supports it (BSD and GNU do, but it's not specified in POSIX) you could use `-execdir` to execute the command in the directory so you could just do

```
find . -name jndi.properties -execdir git mv {} environment.properties \;
```

Comment: This will not help with git status

Comment: I was not aware of the `-execdir` possibility. thanks.!

Comment: @AlexeyTen it seems to keep the deleted part of the status, but I don't see the add part with my solution, so it half-helps with the `git status`